# Connecting Pentaho Spoon Data Integration with Business Analytics Web Localhost

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, cassandra-2.0, kettle, pentaho-ctools

I am doing an usecase with Pentaho - Cassandra.

I installed Pentaho Business Analytics - successfully.. and connected to locahost. localhost:8080/pentaho. In the DataSources (Manage Data Sources) I can see MySQL, Postgres, etc. But my objective is to connect with Cassandra DB with Pentaho.

Pentaho suggested to use Pentaho Spoon - Data Integration. Installed Pentaho Spoon Data Integration successfully and connected Cassandra with that. I can visualize the Cassandra Schema in Pentaho Spoon.,etc.

Now I want to visualize the Cassandra Data in Pentaho BA Server. Can anyone help me to connect with. (I tried adding database using JDBC too. doesnt seem to be working).

And also, from the pentaho documentation, 
I can view the services and status in Pentaho web : 
List the services that are running: http://localhost:9080/pentaho-di/kettle/listServices
List the status of the service: http://localhost:9080/pentaho-di/kettle/Status

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to me you will not able to achieve this directly, you can extract the data from cassandra load into any sql like postgres or mysql.
if you find direct solution then keep this question updated.